# Rails - assign value to field when a form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have the following form in a view.

```
<%=form_for @currency do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Days" %>
    <%= f.select(:prediction_days, options_for_select(1..30)) %>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I want a field to change any time the user submits the form, something like this:

```
<% f.assign(:prediction_type, "neural network") %>
```

I can't make the assignment in the controller because I have two forms in the same view so I wouldn't know which one of them was submitted.

Comment: I never seen `assign`, if you want to pass value from form, why don't you use `hidden_field`

Comment: So I should write something like `hidden_field(:prediction_type, :neural_network)` ?

Comment: `<%= f.hidden_field :prediction_type, :value => :neural_network%>` or  `<%= hidden_field_tag :prediction_type, :neural_network %>`